# Enable htpasswd in zend-framework project for a particular action/url or a controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I want to use password protection for a zend-framework project using .htpasswd. I am able to enable htpasswd in public/index.php i.e project entirely but what i want to achieve is enable password protection for a particular controller/action only.

> Say, I have a controller by name UserController and action editUserAction. And another controller by name PublicController with action listUserAction. What I want to achieve is enable password protection for usercontroller/edit-user action. i.e. whenever a user tries to access url : http://myhost/myproject/user/edit-user  User should be prompted for username and password but the rest of the urls should be accessible.

Is this possible ??? Is this possible using .htpasswd and .htaccess in zend projects ???

Answer (score 0):

Check out basic HTTP Authentication with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

You don't actually need to use a .htaccess file but can build the password prompt right into your controllers.

Comment: I do know about http-auth but I was just trying if it can be achievable using .htaccess. Plus the reason I am not using http-auth is I am running on fcgi and running http-auth in fcgi is not that easy

Comment: As far as i know that's not possible with mod_auth, might be wrong so wait for more clever ppl to answer :)