# Can I use .htpasswd method to protect a Zend Framework 2 Module

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I have an Admin module for backend. I think i don't need a db table to hold usernames and passwords. i want to use basic authentication with .htpasswd if possible.

Comment: Have you searched the site?

Comment: do you mean zf2 site? yes i found this [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.http.html) but i am confused on what job it does and if works for me.

Comment: I was more thinking about posts like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600925/enable-htpasswd-in-zend-framework-project-for-a-particular-action-url-or-a-contr?rq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013083/htpasswd-secure-specific-files-in-zend-framework)

Comment: As I see it all requests are directed through your bootstrap file

Comment: ok in the first link you sent me says that i have to make a login prompt in my controller. so i'll try to use this advice in combination with the link i sent you.

Comment: if it works i will answer my question below...

Comment: That would be nice for future readers. :-)